# Why in Strict mode in Javascript it isn't allowed to use with statement?

Tags: javascript

In my js code file when I use with statement in strict mode it shows error:

'with' is not allowed in strict mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strict mode disallowed the `with` statement for several reasons. Many of them are covered in the MDN article on the `with` statement [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with#:%7E:text=why%20with%20statements%20are%20not%20desirable). The short version is that when you use an identifier in a `with`, it's impossible to tell just by looking at the code (static analysis) what that will resolve to, because what it resolves to depends on the contents of the objects in question.

Consider:

```
with (o1) {
    with (o2) {
        with (o3) {
            foo = "bar";
        }
    }
}
```

What happens? Is that setting `o3.foo`? `o2.foo`? `o1.foo`? A global `foo`? The answer is: it depends on whether `o3` already has a `foo` property, whether `o2` already has a `foo` property, and whether `o1` already has a `foo` property. So there's no way to tell just by looking at that code.

Gratuitous example:

```js
var foo = "x";
function test(num, o1, o2, o3) {
    console.log();
    console.log(`Test: ${num}:`);
    foo = "x";
    console.log("Before:", JSON.stringify({o1, o2, o3, globalFoo: foo}, null, 4));
    with (o1) {
        with (o2) {
            with (o3) {
                foo = "bar";
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("After:", JSON.stringify({o1, o2, o3, globalFoo: foo}, null, 4));
}

test("o1 has a 'foo'", {foo: "x"}, {}, {});
test("o2 has a 'foo'", {}, {foo: "x"}, {});
test("o3 has a 'foo'", {}, {}, {foo: "x"});
test("They all have a 'foo'", {foo: "x"}, {foo: "x"}, {foo: "x"});
test("None of them has a 'foo'", {}, {}, {});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

This makes it difficult or impossible for us humans to reason about the code, and makes it difficult or impossible for JavaScript engines to meaningfully optimize the code. There are also performance implications: any reference to an unqualified identifier (like `foo` in the above) has to be first checked against the object that's the subject of the `with` statement to see if the object has that property. Those checks are cheap, but not free. So in the "None of them has a 'foo'" test above, the JavaScript engine has to check all three of those objects before it sets the global one (in that teste) or, even worse, defaults to the [Horror of Implicit Global Creation](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) (something else that strict mode fixes).

Answer (score -1):

Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues, is it is forbidden in strict mode 
Best practice: Don’t use a with statement. instead try using [IIFE](http://2ality.com/2011/06/with-statement.html)

[1](http://2ality.com/2011/06/with-statement.html): http://2ality.com/2011/02/javascript-variable-scoping-and-its.html 
you can also take a look at [JavaScript’s with statement and why it’s deprecated](http://2ality.com/2011/06/with-statement.html)